# Check if the signal is on the same value for a period of time in simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

I want to determine if sine wave signal is null.
In other words I can't compare agains 0 because sine wave signal are bidirectional what I want to do is if the signal has a value of 0 for a period of time than stop the simulation.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the stop block might be helpful for you: [link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/stopsimulation.html;jsessionid=7e00031f427cc8d7226c107a76d5). What I would do is use a window size using a [buffer](https://www.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/buffer.html?searchHighlight=buffer&s_tid=doc_srchtitle), sum it and compare to zero. Using the buffer size you could set the size of the window you compare. You might use a buffer overlap for it, for example:  
 `Output buffer size = window`  
 `Buffer overlap = window-1`  
  `Initial conditions = 1`  
  The intial condition is used to make sure you won't stop the simulation on the first run.

Comment: By the way, I can't see your picture so I might be missing something...

Comment: Another thing I've just remembered is you might use a small bias to make sure you're close enough to zero.